# Xamarin iOS list of WiFi networks available

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin

I am developing a iOS app with Xamarin - Visual Studio and need to scan the list of WiFi networks available. I know it is possible for more recent versions of iOS (at least iOS 10) but can not find any C# demo code or even figure our what class to use.

Does any one have a demo code or can point me into the right direction?

Comment: I have been able to get current WiFi with NEHotspotConfigurationManager indeed. I have examples of apps that browse the WiFi in range, so it is definitly possible

Comment: With private-API / Non-store apps sure, otherwise using `NEHotspotHelper` you can create hotspot helper apps (with special entitlement granted from Apple).

Comment: The apps I am referring to are commercial apps that can be downloaded from the app store. They display the list of wiFi networks - typically for configuring smart home devices. Still not sure what to do with NEHotspotHelper. Any C# code would help

Comment: Not sure which specific Smart device|apps you are talking about, but each device has different methods, some use HomeKit, some transfer that data via bluetooth, some require you connect to the device's adhoc wifi and then it provides the info, etc... Review the Apple technical doc to see if any of the iOS APIs meet your requirements https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/qa/qa1942/_index.html (`A: iOS does not have a general-purpose API for Wi-Fi scanning and configuration. However, there are a number of special-purpose APIs, and one of these may be appropriate for your product.....`)

Comment: How old is this docs? The access to Wifi in range is very recent, most smarthome apps used to request to change the wifi in settings a year ago as only the current WiFi was accessible. Now most apps let browse the list of WiFi in the app itself. There is a way to get the list WiFi networks at range.

Comment: I know it covers changes up to and including iOS 11, we did an enterprise app in iOS 12 and had to use private APIs to get the AP info needed for that app, Apple referred us back to that doc and restated that nothing had changed regarding its question of "On iOS, how can my app scan for nearby Wi-Fi networks?" as it is a user privacy concern for apps to collect such info, which I do understand as it is a privacy|location issue. Personally I would love to see how to do it via public APIs as I have a 3d mapping / triangulation wifi utility that I would love to port over from Xamarin.Android